# Performance and uses of pointers in C#

Tags: c#, .net, pointers

Does using pointers in c# have any significant performance advantages compared to using only managed code? What would the best use cases for pointers be in c#? I dont really have any specific examples in mind and I have never needed to use them before. It seems like using pointers you could manipulate data faster but perhaps its all just trivial in the end. The only reason I am even thinking about them is because I am working on creating a Matrix class (Learning purposes only) and I want to try to make all the calculations as efficient as possible.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Does using pointers in c# have any significant performance advantages compared to using only managed code?

Sometimes.

> What would the best use cases for pointers be in c#?

Extremely performance sensitive code, and interoperability with existing unmanaged code.

> I dont really have any specific examples in mind and I have never needed to use them before.

I've been writing C# code for about a decade now and I don't recall ever needing to use pointers in actual "line of business" code. Test cases, sure. But not for production.

> I want to try to make all the calculations as efficient as possible.

I hear that a lot on StackOverflow. No, you actually don't want that. You want to make them as efficient as possible *given a certain budget*. You are probably not willing to invest billions of dollars in new math chip fabrication, for example.  **Some people are willing to do that**, but you're not one of them.  Some people have that kind of money to spend and problems that they can solve at a profit if they have the technology.  You're probably willing to make it as efficient as possible *given a certain set of existing technologies* and *given a certain amount of time and effort you're willing to put into it*. Because your aim isn't actually to write fast math, your aim is to learn how to optimize a program.

In that case, *learn how to optimize a program*.  The way you optimize a program is by using *profiling tools* to identify problem spots in the code, and *then*, based on *data*, decide whether to explore the costs and benefits of an unsafe code solution. It could be, for example, that most of your cost is due to cache misses and that what you really need is better locality rather than fewer array range checks. Or maybe you'll discover that for your problem space, memoization is a better technique. There are lots of ways to make a program faster, but you can't know if you're getting any better without data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I didn't think my question would merit a response from the Great Eric Lippert!!...I had to look up memoization so I might try exploring that some but I will give up on the pointers for what I am doing.

Answer (score 3):

There's no definitive answer to this question, but using `unsafe` code with pinned structures (what you call "pointers") can have performance benefits when, for example, you are looping through an array in a very tight loop, need the highest speed possible, but don't need bounds checking.  Your mileage is going to vary depending on what you are doing in the loop, but I've seen 10% speed increases by simply declaring a method `unsafe`.

Comment: You cannot have seen speed increased by declaring a method unsafe because that does nothing.

Comment: Nevertheless, that's what happened.  I'm guessing declaring it `unsafe` turned off the bounds checking on the array I was traversing.

Comment: `unsafe` isn't the only way to get a speedup from eliminating bounds checking: The jitter can optimize out some bounds checking. In a trivial loop over an array, such as `for(int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++) sum += data[i];`, the jitter will see that the bounds will never be exceeded, and will generate code without bounds checking.

Answer (score 1):

There are two main use cases for pointers in C#:

1. You *have* to: For native interop, or unmanaged memory data structures.
2. You want to get rid of array bounds checking or do some other unverifiable stuff.

In other cases it does not help. It also does not help with arrays where the bounds check is eliminated anyway.

It can also hurt code quality with the current JIT because it is not particularly optimized for raw pointers.

In any case: it is important to understand *why* it can help so you can predict where it will be helpful and where it will be useless.

Going unsafe in C# is *nothing* compared to what a C compiler does. A C compiler does things the JIT has never heard of. It is not a "C mode". (The current JIT is not good which also does not help).

Answer (score 1):

Using unmanaged code is always going to be faster to run; using managed code is always going to be faster to market. The decision on how much unmanaged code is needed to make your application **fast enough** to subsequently lean on hardware improvements is an engineering trade-off.

The standard approach is to go primarily for the "faster to market", and then tune key known problem areas after the fact. This has significant advantages:

1. The time gained by writing clean managed code is "in the bank", and can efficiently be refocused as necessary to address known problems.
2. It is easier to rewrite clean managed code for better performance, than to recover time spent writing highly-tuned code that was unnecessary.

The clear corollary here is that it is safer to lean towards writing more managed code, than the reverse.

Answer (score 0):

Almost everything is faster when you go unmanaged. *How much* faster, depends on many factors. Pick the most critical parts and do some testing.

Comment: Not true for the current JIT - empirically it has trouble with unsafe IL instructions because that is an uncommon occurrence. There are cases which don't work out nicely (for example, inlining).

Answer (score 0):

It's completely dependent on how you write the code inside the unsafe block. Unmanaged code has a much higher performance cap, however, if you don't write it correctly the performance will probably be much worse than what C# offers by default. For example if you're using pointers to achieve more efficient access of elements in an array the performance gains will be large. If you're just using them as a reference to an object you'd normally allocate with `Obj myObj = new Obj()` it probably won't be any different.